# How do I create a mat-line with plenty of block content?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using ordinary flex-box I would do this:

```css
.container {
 border: solid 1px black; 
 width: 30em; 
 
 display: flex; 
 flex-flow: row nowrap; 
 
 align-items: center; 
}

.icon {
 width: 5em;
 height: 5em; 
 
 background-color: #fdd; 
}

.button {
 width: 5em; 
 height: 5em;
 background-color: #dfd; 
}

.content {
 flex: 1 0 auto; 
}

p {
 border: solid 1px #aaa; 
 margin: 2px; 
}
```

```html
<div class = "container"> 

<div class ="icon"></div> 

<div class ="content">
<p> 1 </p> 
<p> 2 </p>
<p> 3 </p> 
<p> 4 </p> 
<p> 5 </p>
<p> 6 </p> 
</div> 

<div class ="button"></button>

</div>
```

Easy.

Unfortunately with Angular's `mat-list-item` and `mat-line` it doesn't seem to like `mat-line` that contain content like this. Here's what I'm trying:

```
<mat-list-item >

  <img mat-list-avatar [src]="property.photos[0]"/> 

  <div mat-line>
      <p> 1 </p> 
      <p> 2 </p>
      <p> 3 </p> 
      <p> 4 </p> 
      <p> 5 </p>
      <p> 6 </p> 
   </div>

  <button mat-icon-button> 
      <mat-icon aria-label="Edit Property">edit</mat-icon>
  </button>

</mat-list-item>
```

And I get a bunch of overflowing content.

[image]

It looks like it's because angular is assigning a fixed height to the list item.

Is there a way to make this work using the angular material framework?

The reason I'm trying to do this, is because the content within the `mat-line` is actually another rendered component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, one silly-but-it-works hack, is to put in three empty `mat-line` divs.

```
<mat-list-item >

  <img mat-list-avatar [src]="property.photos[0]"/> 
  <div mat-line/>
  <div mat-line/> 
  <div mat-line/> 

  <div mat-line>
      <p> 1 </p> 
      <p> 2 </p>
      <p> 3 </p> 
      <p> 4 </p> 
      <p> 5 </p>
      <p> 6 </p> 
   </div>

  <button mat-icon-button> 
      <mat-icon aria-label="Edit Property">edit</mat-icon>
  </button>

</mat-list-item>
```

This will change the `mat-list-item` styling to do `height:auto` and will size properly.